# Replace values from an array in string non case sensitive in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, string

My code is as follows:

```
array.forEach(el => {
  string = string.replace(el, `censored`);
});
```

array : my array of words that I want to censor.
string : the string that the words need censoring.

My issue is that this process is  quite slow and also if the word in my string is written using capitals, it's getting missed.
Any ideas how should I solve this issue?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can use regex

```
let array = ['mate']
let string = 'Hello Mate, how are you mate?'

let re = new RegExp(array.join("|"),"gi");
let str = string.replace(re, 'censored');
```

output:

```
"Hello censored, how are you censored?"
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much, that works like a treat.

Comment: Glad it worked! consider marking it as a correct answer :)

Comment: this is a good solution but the blocked list is likely to grow. If it were 10000 words would this solution be efficient?

Comment: I am not planning to have 10000 words that need censoring...at least not for now. If there is another solution, please post it. I am open for other solutions as well.